# Alpine apk etc/apk/world file

Tags: linux, alpine-linux, package-managers

Didn't found anything on the web about it.

I'm using Alpine Linux package management with apk and I'm trying to understand how it works and what are the related files it uses.

What is the purpose of Alpine apk (package manager) `world` file?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The world file contains explicitly installed packages. [(from alpine user handbook)](https://docs.alpinelinux.org/user-handbook/0.1a/Working/apk.html)

You can edit it by hand and run `apk add` or `apk del` to execute the package operation.